# Are There Any Cron Jobs Alternative?

Tags: php, cron, jobs

Cron Jobs are closed on my server and server admin doesn't accept open it. Because , cron jobs slowing server etc. So, i need an alternative.

I have to run a php file (**cron.php**) every 2 minutes.

So, how can i do this ?

Comment: Is `cron.php` served from a web server or is it just a local script?

Comment: The short answer is to get a better host...

Comment: @Jesse, it's served from a web server and reachable with a browser

Comment: Subscibe to a (free) web site monitoring service, and schedule your [url]/cron.php. You can have your webpage page return something meaningfull and configure the monitoring service to notify you on that response.

Answer (score 17):

Even though the question was posted a while ago, I just had the same problem but found a solution (based on [Kissaki's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4662102/2299326), thanks!) and thought I'd post it here for anyone still looking for a possible solution.

**Prerequisites:**

- SSH access
- Python

**Code (python):**

```
from subprocess import call
import time
while True:
    call(["php","cron.php"])
    time.sleep(120)
```

Comment: So I need to call the python script over ssh once ?

Comment: Correct. If you have support for "screen", you could do it in the background as well.

Answer (score 2):

Depends on your access on the box.

PHP itself will not be able to run standalone that well. You could do a script which tries to increase it’s execution time constantly, sleeping and checking for new jobs regularly. But that is sub-optimal as you’ll have to access it via browser once, and the script would have to make sure it only runs once.

With shell access you could run the php script on the shell, which would prevent it from being callable from public and having to run it via webbrowser.

With shell access you could also run a program that provides a (cron) service for you. Be it a Java, Python, or other program.

Cron jobs shouldn’t slow the server always. That depends on the job that is run. If it’s your jobs that are so expensive your admin will probably not be okay with working around the closed cron jobs and slowing the server again anyway and may take further action to prevent you from working around.

Answer (score 2):

There are several Cron alternatives for Linux.
Like,

1. Anacron - Anacron is a periodic command scheduler just like cron. The only difference is that it does not need your computer to be always running.
2. fcron - Fcron is the best of both cron and anacron. It doesn’t require your computer to be running 24×7, and it can work with tasks on an hourly or minute basis.
3. Hcron
4. Jobber
   etc.

> For future reading refer to [this article](https://www.maketecheasier.com/cron-alternatives-linux/).

Answer (score 0):

Just an addition to the Answers. Rare case scenario.

If your application is having frequent amount of database operations then you can maintain a separate table where the the one column will work as a measure when to run the script. Example as below

Table CRON_RUN

```
last_run
----------
12-09-2018 11:55:12 (dd-mm-yyyy H:M:S)
```

Now in your application a check can be performed every time when those frequent db operations occurs and check if the last_run date and the current date is having **x**  difference . **X** is difference in time you want to run the script. 2 minutes in your case. Also if the difference is more then or equal to 2 minutes then the update statement will run to update the last_run column with the current date time and the next statement will be you cron.php script  .

Answer (score 0):

Best Solution:- Use serialise file to save status or DB. Check this file on every request and run script when need. If you need to manage these jobs more widely and run shell commands and you have permission to install services. Use SartajPHP NativeApp as service. You can also control your jobs via browser and see live errors and fix them.